# How do i add fileds dynamically using codeIgniter with script?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i need add fields dynamically in my view form. i have a script function for that.. but i don't know how to include in that script into **codeIgniter.**

my controller -

```
class uploadfile extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct()
    {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->helper('url');}
 //index function
    function index()
    {
       //load file upload form
        $this->load->view('upload_file_view');}}
```

my view -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/myscript.js");?>" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="doc" class=" control-label">SUPPORT DOCUMENT</label>
         <div class="multi-field-wrapper ">
           <div class="multi-fields">
             <div class="multi-field">
 <input id="doc" type="text" class="form-control" name="attachment[]">
</div> </div>
<button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button> </div>
```

and my script path - **C:\xampp\htdocs\samplecod\assets\js**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a easy way to add multiple fields in view page

```
`<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 text-left">Description</div>

            <div class="field_wrapper">
                <input type="textarea" name="descrip[]" value="" size="35px" /><input type="text" name="voucher_no[]" value="" size="7px"/><input type="text" name="price[]" value=""size="7px"/>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/add-icon.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div></div></div>`
```

for this form this is the script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 20; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="descrip[]" value="" size="35px"/><input type="text" name="voucher_no[]" value="" size="7px"/><input type="text" name="price[]" value="" size="7px"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/remove-icon.png'); ?>"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
```